# Best Cloud SQL Proxy setup in Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql

Based on its [github page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy#to-use-from-kubernetes), it is recommended to be set up as a sidecar container as opposed to a cluster service. My question would be, is there any possible issues (e.g. performance, no. of connections) if I have a lot of pods that has cloud sql proxy as a sidecar container? It seems reasonable to create a service instead.

Let me know if I am missing anything from here.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer as community wiki as the answer for this question could be opinionated.

> Based on its [github page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy#to-use-from-kubernetes), it is recommended to be set up as a sidecar container as opposed to a cluster service.

Not only the site you mentioned but also the official documentation of `CloudSQL`:

> To access a Cloud SQL instance from an application running in Google Kubernetes Engine, you can use either the Cloud SQL Proxy (with public or private IP), or connect directly using a private IP address.
>
> **The Cloud SQL Proxy is the recommended way to connect to Cloud SQL**, even when using private IP. This is because the proxy provides strong encryption and authentication using IAM, which can help keep your database secure.
>
> *[Cloud.google.com: SQL: Docs: MySQL: Connect Kubernetes Engine: Introduction](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#introduction)*

---

> It seems reasonable to create a service instead.

You can read why using proxy is more advised instead of spawning a service:

> We recommend this over running as a separate service for several reasons:
>
> - Prevents your SQL traffic from being exposed locally; the proxy provides encryption on outgoing connections, but you need to limit exposure for incoming connections
> - Prevents a single point of failure; each application's access to your database is independent from the others, making it more resilient.
> - Limits access to the proxy, allowing you to use IAM permissions per application rather than exposing the database to the entire cluster
> - Allows you to scope resource requests more accurately; because the proxy consumes resources linearly to usage, this pattern allows you to more accurately scope and request resources to match your applications as it scales
>
> *[Cloud.google.com: SQL: Docs: MySQL: Connect Kubernetes Engine: Run the CloudSQL proxy as a sidecar](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#run_the_cloud_sql_proxy_as_a_sidecar)*

---

As for the number of active connections (it's different depending on used solution):

- *[Cloud.google.com: SQL: Docs: MySQL: Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quotas)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: SQL: Docs: PostgreSQL: Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/quotas)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: SQL: Docs: SQL Server: Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserve/quotas)*

Also it could be beneficiary to add (effective management of connections to a database):

- *[Cloud.google.com: SQL: Docs: MySQL: Manage connections](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: SQL: Docs: MySQL: SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)*
- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: Can I run the CloudSQL proxy as a daemonset in kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340003/can-i-run-the-cloudsql-proxy-as-a-daemon-set-in-kubernetes)*

Comment: @alexishacks, does it answer your question ? If so, you may consider voting on it or accepting it. Please, take a look at the following section in Help Center: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)